# Cannot resolve method getContext() ou getItem()

Tags: java, android

Oi,

Tentando passar os dados de um ArrayList, mas aparece o erro nos metodos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Sua classe ListaAdapter precisa estender `ArrayAdapter<Item>`.

Exemplo:

```java
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);
        }



        return v;
    }

}
```

Da uma olhadinha se isso aqui ajuda: [ArrayAdapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)